# Is this a decimal rule?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assume you'd need to calculate $\sqrt2$

We come to $1,414213562$.

Now, calculate $1,414213562^2$.

Which clearly gives; $1,9999999...$.

However, for some reason my tutor has come to:

$\sqrt2 = 1,4142136$.

Why did he round this number up on 7 decimals? Are there general rules for rounding up numbers on 7 decimals?

P.s. my apologies for the used language, I'm not the greatest English speaker.

Comment: We used to round up when the next digit is greater than 5.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima, why did you do so? Isn't it quite risky to round up numbers because it can heavily influence the outcome of a question?

Comment: Rounding a number like $15.9$ up to $16$ is a better approximation than rounding it down to $15$ as it is closer.

Comment: "We come to $1,414213562.$" What do you mean "we." That number is also rounded...

Comment: If you are producing a final numerical answer, it will necessarily be an approximation. If you are handling an intermediate value, it may be better to keep the $\sqrt 2$ representation in order to defer and perhaps avoid the rounding error eg. $(\sqrt 2 +1)(\sqrt 2 -1)$

Answer (score 4):

The rounding to $7$ decimals was arbitrary. Any decimal representation of $\sqrt2$ (and in general, of any irrational number) will be an approximation. The '$\approx$' sign should've been used instead of '$=$'. Or alternatively $\sqrt2 = 1,4142135...$ where the dots indicate the decimal continues.

Note for rounding, the last digit is rounded up if the digit after is $5$ or greater, else it is rounded down. This minimizes the error. Here it ensures

$$|\sqrt2 - a| \leq\frac{1}{2}(10^{-7})$$

where $a$ is the rounded approximation.